# VPN server setup on a 2008 R2 Hyper-V VPS

Tags: vpn, vps, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, pptp, rras

I am renting a Windows 2008 R2 VPS (Hyper-V). It has 1 network adapter which has a public IP statically assigned.

I wish to allow incoming VPN connections, so that I can access SMB for a central file server.

I have setup RRAS, and VPN'ing in works fine -- but when I uncheck the 'Use default gateway' on the client-side (as I do not wish for clients public internet traffic to flow through the VPN server), name resolution stops working.. so \servername\sharename stops working. Likewise, ping servername also says could not find the host. \10.0.0.50\sharename works still, but this is not ideal.

I've tried setting the RRAS properties to give out addresses from DHCP and statically assigned pool. I tried to install DHCP server but it appears to only be able to bind to the physical adapter.

Can anyone help, please? Apologies about my low accept-ratio, I will be wrapping up all my other questions at *some point*.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a hosts file on the client machine that points to the LAN IP of your VPS. That would be a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not something I want to do. If I wanted to fiddle on client machines I'd just set their shortcut to the SMB link to use an IP UNC.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the FQDN of the server when trying to access it's shares.